# Aggregation based off of nested document field with filters on nested document and parent

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "accountId": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "storeProductId": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "storeSchemaId": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "yoyoValues": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "yoyoNameId": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "dataType": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "languageId": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "value_Number": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "value_Raw": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to get the max and min values for value_number for all nested documents with yoyoNameId of 3 that also has a parent document with an accountId of 1285 and  storeSchemaId of 241.

Everytime I've tried, I've been unable to properly filter the nested documents so it ends up being the min and max values for all nested documents with the correct parent document values.

I've tried several different queries but my most recent one is as follows:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "filter-layer": {
            "filters": {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "accountId": 1285
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "yoyoSchemaId": 241
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "yoyoValues",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "yoyoValues.yoyoNameId": 3
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggs": {
                "yoyoValues": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "yoyoValues"
                    },
                    "inner": {
                        "filter": {
                            "term": {
                                "yoyoValues.yoyoNameId": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "min_value": {
                                "min": {
                                    "field": "yoyoValues.value_Number"
                                }
                            },
                            "max_value": {
                                "max": {
                                    "field": "yoyoValues.value_Number"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me correct this query? I'm limited to elastic v7.13.